# How to get next input with name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form like this:

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="registerExtenedFirstName">Vorname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registerExtenedFirstName[]" placeholder="Vorname" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="registerExtenedLastName">Nachname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registerExtenedLastName[]" placeholder="Nachname" required="">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="registerExtenedFirstName">Vorname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registerExtenedFirstName[]" placeholder="Vorname" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="registerExtenedLastName">Nachname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registerExtenedLastName[]" placeholder="Nachname" required="">
   </div>
</div>
```

I try to push like this, the first and last name to an dict:

```js
      $('input[name^="registerExtenedFirstName"]').each(function() {
        participants.push({
          key: $(this).val() + $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val(),
          value: $(this).val() + ' ' + $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val()
        });
      });
```

But, when I have names like this

```
Thomas Müller
Bernd Maier
```

after the push I have this:

```js
(2) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {key: "ThomasMüller", value: "Thomas Müller"}
1: {key: "BerndMüller", value: "Bernd Müller"}
```

it pushes only from the first the registerExtenedLastName to every array, and I don't why

Answer (score 1):

I would use another approach - search by `div.form-row`. Here is the example code:

```js
$('.form-row').each(function() {
  participants.push({
    key: $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedFirstName"]').val() + $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val(),
    value: $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedFirstName"]').val() + ' ' + $(this).find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val()
  });
});
```

Comment: While it would work in this example I would not recommend it. `form-row` is used a lot, and might be used more in the OP's code.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - then OP might use a more specific selector like `#my-form > .form-row`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could fix it.
I had to search in the next DOM element like this:

```js
      $('input[name^="registerExtenedFirstName"]').each(function() {
        participants.push({
          key: $(this).val() + $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val(),
          value: $(this).val() + ' ' + $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]').val()
        });
      });
```

Comment: You can also use `$(this).closest(".form-row").find('input[name^="registerExtenedLastName"]')`